# Create mySQL junction table from single table with parent-child relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am working on making a junction table out of a single table that has a parent-child relationship. Here is the basic idea of what I have now:

```
parent    number
1         55
1         56
1         57
0         58
0         59
```

Is it possible to write a query to give me this output?

```
parent    child
55        58
55        59
56        58
56        59
57        58
57        59
```

I know I must be missing something silly here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain all those numbers? It makes no sense to me how you got to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CROSS JOIN` to get the cartesian product of the rows.

```
SELECT  a.number parent,
        b.number child
FROM    TableName a
        CROSS JOIN TableName b
WHERE   a.parent = 1 AND
        b.parent = 0
ORDER   BY a.number, b.number
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94d8/6)